# Gitlab pipeline fails, even though deployment happened on GCP

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci, google-cloud-run

I just created my first CI/CD pipeline on Gitlab, which creates a docker container for a Next.js app, and deploys it on Google Cloud Run.

My cloudbuild.yaml:

```
# File: cloudbuild.yaml
steps:
    # build the container image
  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
    args: [ 'build', '-t', 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/inook-web', '.' ]
    # push the container image
  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
    args: [ 'push', 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/inook-web']
    # deploy to Cloud Run
  - name: "gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud"
    args: ['run', 'deploy', 'inook-web', '--image', 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/inook-web', '--region', 'europe-west1', '--platform', 'managed', '--allow-unauthenticated']
```

My .gitlab-ci.yml:

```
# File: .gitlab-ci.yml
image: docker:latest

stages:          # List of stages for jobs, and their order of execution
  - deploy-test
  - deploy-prod

deploy-test:
  stage: deploy-test
  image: google/cloud-sdk
  services:
    - docker:dind
  script:
    - echo $GCP_SERVICE_KEY > gcloud-service-key.json # Google Cloud service accounts
    - gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file gcloud-service-key.json
    - gcloud config set project $GCP_PROJECT_ID
    - gcloud builds submit . --config=cloudbuild.yaml
```

I get the following error message in the CI/CD pipeline:
https://ibb.co/ZXLWrj1

However, the deployment actually succeeds on GCP: https://ibb.co/ZJjtXzG

Any idea what I can do to fix the pipeline error?

Comment: I'm a bit confused. May I know why you're using both cloudbuild and gitlab ci yml files.

Comment: my git repository is hosted on GitLab, so gitlab ci triggers the Cloudbuild on every push, and deploys the docker container to Cloud Run. Is there a way to directly trigger Cloudbuild from GitLab, without using GitLab CI file?

Comment: can you check this link : https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/automating-builds/build-repos-from-github is it helpful?

Comment: As you can see, the `gcloud builds submit` command returns exit code 1, causing the pipeline to fail. Looks like it has something to do with logging so maybe you could just disable logging somehow…

Comment: Hey @slauth, thanks for your suggestion. However, I don't see the option to disable logs (https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/builds/submit). Only the option to change the source bucket address from default. Also, the logs are being created successfully in the bucket, and the build is also succeeding, but don't know why I am getting exit code 1.

Comment: @DivyaniYadav, your link explains integration with GitHub repository. I checked, there is no native way inbuilt in console which allows me to integrate CI with GitLab repository, which is why I created the .gitlab-ci.yml file in addition to the cloudbuild.yaml file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What worked for me was to add a custom bucket for the gcloud builds submit to push logs to. Thanks @slauth for pointing me in the right direction.

Updated command:

```
gcloud builds submit . --config=cloudbuild.yaml --gcs-log-dir=gs://inook_test_logs
```